# Getting computer hardware information

Tags: python, hardware

I tried to get all information about a computer by python but there is no good library to find something like monitor or keyboard or details of graphic card.

Is it possible to get list of hardware or devices of computers?

Answer (score 2):

I personally find the psutil library interesting for monitoring everything that is going on on your system:

https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil

Moreover, you might have a look at the platform lib, which you can use to gather information, guess what, platform, yes.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/platform.html

If you're on linux, it might be a solution to use some system command like lspci and friends to gather other information as well. See, for instance this: http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/using/lspci

There's also a similar question on stack overflow: [Python, In linux obtain VGA specifications via lspci or HAL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13867696/61903)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `psutil`. Here is a good example that I have created long time ago in Python 2.7:

```
from Tkinter import *
import psutil
import datetime
from multiprocessing import cpu_count



def timeFunc():
    time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%I:%M:%S %p")
    date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

    Label(master, text="System Time").grid(row=16, columnspan=2, sticky='w')

    e13 = Entry(master)
    e13.grid(row=16, column=1)
    e13.insert(10, time)

    Label(master, text="System Date").grid(row=17, columnspan=2, sticky='w')

    e14 = Entry(master)
    e14.grid(row=17, column=1)
    e14.insert(10, date)


def secs2hours(secs):
    mm, ss = divmod(secs, 60)
    hh, mm = divmod(mm, 60)
    return "%d:%02d:%02d (H:M:S)" % (hh, mm, ss)


def bat():
    if not hasattr(psutil, "sensors_battery"):
        # outputList.append("Platform not supported")
        Label(master, text="Status").grid(row=10, columnspan=2, sticky='w')
        e9 = Entry(master)
        e9.grid(row=11, column=1)
        e9.insert(10, "Platform not supported")
        batt = psutil.sensors_battery()
    if batt is None:
        # outputList.append("No battery is installed")
        Label(master, text="Status").grid(row=10, columnspan=2, sticky='w')
        e9 = Entry(master)
        e9.grid(row=11, column=1)
        e9.insert(10, "No battery is installed")

    # print("charge:     %s%%" % round(batt.percent, 2))
    if batt.power_plugged:
        Label(master, text="Charge").grid(row=11, columnspan=2, sticky='w')
        charge = "%s%%" % round(batt.percent, 2)
        e9 = Entry(master)
        e9.grid(row=11, column=1)
        e9.insert(10, charge)

        Label(master, text="Time Left").grid(row=12, columnspan=2, sticky='w')
        z = 'N/A'
        e10 = Entry(master)
        e10.grid(row=12, column=1)
        e10.insert(10, z)

        Label(master, text="Status").grid(row=13, columnspan=2, sticky='w')
        x = ("%s" % (
            "Charging" if batt.percent < 100 else "fully charged"
        ))

        e11 = Entry(master)
        e11.grid(row=13, column=1)
        e11.insert(10, x)

        Label(master, text="Plugged in").grid(row=14, columnspan=2, sticky='w')
        y = "Yes"

        e12 = Entry(master)
        e12.grid(row=14, column=1)
        e12.insert(10, y)

        # outputList.append(y)
        # print("plugged in: yes")
    else:
        Label(master, text="Charge").grid(row=11, columnspan=2, sticky='w')
        charge = "%s%%" % round(batt.percent, 2)
        e9 = Entry(master)
        e9.grid(row=11, column=1)
        e9.insert(10, charge)

        Label(master, text="          ").grid(row=12, columnspan=2, sticky='w')
        Label(master, text="Time Left").grid(row=12, columnspan=2, sticky='w')
        x = ("%s" % secs2hours(batt.secsleft))
        Label(master, text="                  ").grid(row=13, columnspan=2, sticky='w')
        Label(master, text="Status").grid(row=13, columnspan=2, sticky='w')
        y = "%s" % "discharging"
        Label(master, text="          ").grid(row=14, columnspan=2, sticky='w')
        Label(master, text="Plugged in").grid(row=14, columnspan=2, sticky='w')
        z = "No"

        e10 = Entry(master)
        e10.grid(row=12, column=1)
        e10.insert(10, x)

        e11 = Entry(master)
        e11.grid(row=13, column=1)
        e11.insert(10, y)

        e12 = Entry(master)
        e12.grid(row=14, column=1)
        e12.insert(10, z)

        # outputList.append(x)
        # print("Plugged in: no")


def main():
    global outputList

    totalRam = 1.0
    totalRam = psutil.virtual_memory()[0] * totalRam
    totalRam = str("{:.4f}".format(totalRam / (1024 * 1024 * 1024))) + ' GB'

    availRam = 1.0
    availRam = psutil.virtual_memory()[1] * availRam
    availRam = str("{:.4f}".format(availRam / (1024 * 1024 * 1024))) + ' GB'

    ramUsed = 1.0
    ramUsed = psutil.virtual_memory()[3] * ramUsed
    ramUsed = str("{:.4f}".format(ramUsed / (1024 * 1024 * 1024))) + ' GB'

    ramFree = 1.0
    ramFree = psutil.virtual_memory()[4] * ramFree
    ramFree = str("{:.4f}".format(ramFree / (1024 * 1024 * 1024))) + ' GB'

    core = cpu_count()
    ramUsages = str(psutil.virtual_memory()[2]) + '%'
    cpuPer = str(psutil.cpu_percent()) + '%'
    cpuMainCore = psutil.cpu_count(logical=False)

    outputList.append(cpuMainCore)
    outputList.append(core)
    outputList.append(cpuPer)
    outputList.append(totalRam)
    outputList.append(availRam)
    outputList.append(ramUsed)
    outputList.append(ramUsages)
    outputList.append(ramFree)


def clock():
    global outputList
    outputList = []
    main()
    bat()
    timeFunc()
    master.update_idletasks()
    e1 = Entry(master)
    e2 = Entry(master)
    e3 = Entry(master)
    e4 = Entry(master)
    e5 = Entry(master)
    e6 = Entry(master)
    e7 = Entry(master)
    e8 = Entry(master)

    e1.grid(row=1, column=1)
    e2.grid(row=2, column=1)
    e3.grid(row=3, column=1)
    e4.grid(row=5, column=1)
    e5.grid(row=6, column=1)
    e6.grid(row=7, column=1)
    e7.grid(row=8, column=1)
    e8.grid(row=9, column=1)

    e1.insert(10, outputList[0])
    e2.insert(10, outputList[1])
    e3.insert(10, outputList[2])
    e4.insert(10, outputList[3])
    e5.insert(10, outputList[4])
    e6.insert(10, outputList[5])
    e7.insert(10, outputList[6])
    e8.insert(10, outputList[7])

    master.after(1000, clock)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    master = Tk()
    master.title('System Monitor')
    Label(master, text="CPU Info").grid(row=0, columnspan=2, sticky='e')
    Label(master, text="Total CPU CORE").grid(row=1, columnspan=2, sticky='w')
    Label(master, text="Total Logical Processors").grid(row=2)
    Label(master, text="CPU Usages").grid(row=3, columnspan=2, sticky='w')
    Label(master, text="RAM Info").grid(row=4, columnspan=2, sticky='e')
    Label(master, text="Total RAM").grid(row=5, columnspan=2, sticky='w')
    Label(master, text="Available RAM").grid(row=6, columnspan=2, sticky='w')
    Label(master, text="RAM Used").grid(row=7, columnspan=2, sticky='w')
    Label(master, text="RAM Usages").grid(row=8, columnspan=2, sticky='w')
    Label(master, text="RAM Free").grid(row=9, columnspan=2, sticky='w')
    Label(master, text="Battery Info").grid(row=10, columnspan=2, sticky='e')
    Label(master, text="Additional").grid(row=15, columnspan=2, sticky='e')
    Label(master, text=u'\N{COPYRIGHT SIGN}' " foysal_nibir 2018", fg='red').grid(row=19, columnspan=2, sticky='n', )

    outputList = []

    clock()
    master.update_idletasks()

    master.mainloop()
```

Enjoy, have a nice day.