# How to secure a python program (with serial keys)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, security, tkinter

I am developing a paid program in Python with Tkinter. How can I make the program user-specific. I don't want people sharing their license. If there is no better option than serial keys. What is the best way of doing this? Doesn't have to be top of the line security. Just don't want people to share their license..

Comment: I don't know if it is possible with python, because it is easy to modify the python code.

Comment: It doesn't have to be too secure. What would be my best option?

Comment: >>>"It doesn't have to be too secure." 
First of all define criterions.

Comment: 2-factor authentication locked to a cell-phone number? A USB hardware dongle? Facial recognition? Frankly I think any of this is more likely to hurt than help your sales.

Comment: You're asking to prevent the owner of a general-purpose computer from being able to put that general-purpose computer to arbitrary uses. This is, in short, a very hard problem -- in the "computer science research subject" meaning of hard. There's been a lot of work on it over the course of decades, sure, but none of that work is going to make your life easy right now.

Comment: ...the case when you can do this *easily* is if your users will accept your program needing an Internet connection to work -- then you put some critical piece of the program's logic on the other side of a network connection. If that logic is hard to redevelop, *then* you've actually got some security -- but at the expense of some likely-very-unhappy users.

Comment: To be clear -- I've built copy protection professionally, and I've broken it professionally (to let someone use a product they'd paid for made by a company that was long-out-of-business, after the dongle that came with their accounting software broke). Breaking it is easier: To build a system it has to stand against all attacks; to break it, you need find only *one* attack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could embed the machine ID and user ID in your code to check at startup.

```
import getpass
userID = getpass.getuser()
import socket
machineID = socket.gethostname()
```

Also see (not verified but here it goes): [Getting computer hardware information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33449577/getting-computer-hardware-information)
Also at the Windows command prompt, you can use `systeminfo` which will give you the whole computer information. From Python you can run `os.system('systeminfo > lolo.txt')` which will display and pipe to the text file.
I was looking a the same problem you have. Hope it helps

Comment: What's to stop the user from NOPping out that check (which is to say, modifying the bytecode/executable/&c installed on their system to no longer perform it)?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, is just a deterrent. Even compiled C++ programs can be reverse engineered. It seems that what software distributors use of the program check back on their Web site at startup is the most common now but I assume that can also be reverse engineered.

Comment: Yes, it absolutely can (be reverse engineered). If you want something reliable, you need software that *requires data it doesn't have and can't otherwise acquire*.  In the past, I've stored key material inside the video streams for ads the user was supposed to watch; or (at a different startup with a different business model) in hardware with battery-backed memory tied to a tamper sensor. And none of that is perfect -- all one can reasonably aim for (without a Sony-level R&D budget) is to make the business types feel warm and fuzzy, without being too expensive or onerous on the user.

Comment: ...but what you're doing here doesn't even achieve that; it's pure snake oil. J. Random high school student could defeat it in an afternoon.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use python to write code, but keep embedded secrets, your best bet will be to compile to binary and ship only binary to users.  [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) is a good place to start your research. There are several alternatives to PyInstaller.

Comment: This doesn't do a remotely adequate job. PyInstaller packages and ships a Python interpreter + bytecode. The bytecode is just as trivial to decompile as any other Python program.

Comment: Which is to say -- even an *incompetent* reverse engineer will have no impediment from this, or any similar tool (cx_Freeze, py2exe, etc).